# selecting one row per data with aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

```
         price
---------------------
        id | int (PK)
unit_price | number
   part_id | int (FK)
      line | int
```

With a unique constraint on `part_id` and `line` (so parts can have multiple prices differentiated by the "line")

To visualize:

```
id | unit_price | part_id | line
--------------------------------
 1 |     100.00 |       1 |    1
 2 |     150.00 |       1 |    2
 3 |      90.00 |       1 |    3
 --------------------------------
 4 |      75.00 |       2 |    1
 5 |      70.00 |       2 |    2
 --------------------------------
 6 |      90.00 |       3 |    1
 7 |      95.00 |       3 |    2
```

I need to write a query that will take the *lowest* 'line' for each part and show the price, so the output will be this:

```
id | unit_price | part_id | line
--------------------------------
 1 |     100.00 |       1 |    1
 4 |      75.00 |       2 |    1
 6 |      90.00 |       3 |    1
```

I started with this query:

```
SELECT min(line), unit_price, part_id
FROM price
GROUP BY ... ?
```

But I quickly realized that if I add `unit_price` and `part_id` to the `GROUP BY` clause, then it will basically give me the original output (everything) because each `unit_price` is unique. But I can't `GROUP BY part_id` by itself, because `unit_price` needs to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Should I even be using the aggregate `min` function to select only *one* row per `part_id`? I think I might be barking up the wrong tree with `GROUP BY`. I only present it in the question to show the things I've tried.

In my dataset, not all prices are guaranteed to start with '1', so a `= 1` condition won't work. I need the minimum. Also, I'm using MySQL, but I think that perhaps shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a common approach using a `join` with a subquery that uses `min`:

```
select p.id, p.unit_price, p.part_id, p.line
from price p join (
    select part_id, min(line) as line
    from price
    group by part_id
    ) t on p.part_id = t.part_id and p.line = t.line
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query

Query :-

```
select p1.* from price as p1
where p1.id = ( select p2.id from price as p2
                where p2.part_id = p1.part_id
                order by p2.line asc limit 0,1)
group by p1.id
```